# Problem on TaskEither sequenceArray function for processing different types of return type

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

I am working on functional programming using [`fp-ts`](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts) library.
Here is my code and my problem:

```
import * as TE from 'fp-ts/TaskEither';
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/lib/function';

function getName(): TE.TaskEither<Error, String> {
  return TE.right('John Doe');
}

function getAge(): TE.TaskEither<Error, number> {
  return TE.right(40);
}

export function seqArrayTest(): TE.TaskEither<Error, string> {
  return pipe(
    TE.sequenceArray([
         getName(), 
         getAge(),
       ]),
    TE.chain(([name, age]) => {
      return TE.right(`Name: ${name}, Age: ${age}`);
    }),
  );
}
```

Here:

1. I have two functions: `getName` and `getAge` returning `TaskEither` with different value types.
2. I am calling them parallel using `TE.sequenceArray`.
3. After the computation, I am just chaining the response and returning another `TaskEither`.

**During compilation**, on `TE.sequenceArray([getName(), getAge()])`, it shows below error for `getAge()`:

> Type 'TaskEither<Error, number>' is not assignable to type 'TaskEither<Error, String>'.
> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'String'.ts(2322)

**But my understanding is**: `TE.sequenceArray` should take an array of functions with different return types that are wrapped with `TaskEither` and it will return an array of responses sequentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Souperman answer is correct in this context.`TE.sequenceArray` expects an array of `TaskEithers` with the same `Right` types.

If we want to process an array of `TaskEither` and the return type is different, then we may use `sequenceT`.

Here is the modified code:

```
import * as TE from "fp-ts/TaskEither";
import { pipe } from "fp-ts/lib/function";
import { sequenceT } from "fp-ts/Apply";

function getName(): TE.TaskEither<Error, String> {
  return TE.right("John Doe");
}

function getAge(): TE.TaskEither<Error, number> {
  return TE.right(30);
}

export function seqArrayTest(): TE.TaskEither<Error, string> {
  return pipe(
    sequenceT(TE.ApplyPar)(getName(), getAge()),
    TE.chain(([name, age]) => {
      return TE.right(`Name: ${name}, Age: ${age}`);
    }),
    TE.mapLeft((e) => e)
  );
}
```

Here, `TE.ApplyPar`: Runs computations in parallel. If we want sequential, then we may use `TE.ApplySeq`.

In `TE.chain(([name, age])` parameter `name` is a `string` type, and `age` is a `number` type. And response sequence will based on the calling sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the docs](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/TaskEither.ts.html#sequencearray), `TE.sequenceArray` is expecting an array of TaskEithers with *the same* Right types.

```js
export declare const sequenceArray: <A, E>(arr: readonly TaskEither<E, A>[]) =>
   TaskEither<E, readonly A[]>
```

You could specify that the array is of type `Array<TE.TaskEither<Error, String | number>>` explicitly and it should work as expected.

```js
pipe(
  [getName(), getAge()] as Array<TE.TaskEither<Error, String | number>>,
  TE.sequenceArray,
  // ...
);
```

Unpacking those values in your call to `TE.chain` could theoretically be dangerous, however. You are not guaranteed from within the `chain` call that the array will have two elements. As written it will, but the typechecker cannot infer that. `Do` notation might be a better fit for these scenarios.